# Which Django model should be used for staff members?

Tags: python, django, django-models

For a project (my own pet project) I am doing, I have an app called 'staff'. The ideas is 'staff' will contain list of all staff members in my organization. Now, they have to have an ability to login to the system and check what assets were assigned to them. The question is which built-in model (User, AbstractBaseUser, or AbstractUser) I should use for the 'staff' app? I've started with models.Model, however, I am thinking it might not be correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default User model that has a boolean field called is_staff. Then allow only user with `is_staff==True` to use the restricted system. You can change the value of is_staff in the admin interface. If you want a custom User model, subclass AbstractUser in the models of your staff app, then add this in your settings (if you want that your custom model is used for authentication): `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'AppName.CutomUserModelName'`